# Utilizing rolling() with an apply() function with groups in pd.DataFrame object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the gradient between each row of the same group with

```
def get_gradient(row, row2):
    return (row['foo'] - row2['foo'])/(row['bar'] - row2['bar'])
```

On the example table below:

Running `get_gradient(demo.iloc[0],demo.iloc[1])` would get the first non `np.nan` value.
then `get_gradient(demo.iloc[1],demo.iloc[2])` would get the next value.
However, when `baz` becomes `B`, we shift to a "new window"

```
demo = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'foo':[0.023939,0.180167,0.316840,0.497396,0.632713,0.332927,0.489553,0.677083,0.810815,0.967808],
        'bar':[0.027107,0.070630,0.014774,0.059228,0.033585,0.010692,0.012511,0.011934,0.028882,0.365916],
        'baz':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B',]
    }
)
```

|  | foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.023939 | 0.027107 | A |
| 1 | 0.180167 | 0.07063 | A |
| 2 | 0.31684 | 0.014774 | A |
| 3 | 0.497396 | 0.059228 | A |
| 4 | 0.632713 | 0.033585 | A |
| 5 | 0.332927 | 0.010692 | B |
| 6 | 0.489553 | 0.012511 | B |
| 7 | 0.677083 | 0.011934 | B |
| 8 | 0.810815 | 0.028882 | B |
| 9 | 0.967808 | 0.365916 | B |

I expect to achieve the following table:

|  | foo | bar | baz | grad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.023939 | 0.027107 | A | nan |
| 1 | 0.180167 | 0.07063 | A | 3.58955 |
| 2 | 0.31684 | 0.014774 | A | -2.44688 |
| 3 | 0.497396 | 0.059228 | A | 4.06164 |
| 4 | 0.632713 | 0.033585 | A | -5.27696 |
| 5 | 0.332927 | 0.010692 | B | nan |
| 6 | 0.489553 | 0.012511 | B | 86.1056 |
| 7 | 0.677083 | 0.011934 | B | -325.009 |
| 8 | 0.810815 | 0.028882 | B | 7.89072 |
| 9 | 0.967808 | 0.365916 | B | 0.465808 |

I am aware of `groupby()`, `rolling()` and `apply(,axis=1)`, but unable to determine the correct chaining sequence. What is the best way to chain these methods to form the expected table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it with just the features of a dataframe

```
demo = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'foo':[0.023939,0.180167,0.316840,0.497396,0.632713,0.332927,0.489553,0.677083,0.810815,0.967808],
        'bar':[0.027107,0.070630,0.014774,0.059228,0.033585,0.010692,0.012511,0.011934,0.028882,0.365916],
        'baz':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B',]
    }
)
demo['foo_prev'] = demo.groupby('baz')['foo'].shift()
demo['bar_prev'] = demo.groupby('baz')['bar'].shift()
demo['grad']=(demo['foo'] - demo['foo_prev'])/(demo['bar'] - demo['bar_prev'])
```

and this gives

```
    foo         bar         baz foo_prev    bar_prev    grad
0   0.023939    0.027107    A   NaN         NaN         NaN
1   0.180167    0.070630    A   0.023939    0.027107    3.589550
2   0.316840    0.014774    A   0.180167    0.070630    -2.446881
3   0.497396    0.059228    A   0.316840    0.014774    4.061637
4   0.632713    0.033585    A   0.497396    0.059228    -5.276957
5   0.332927    0.010692    B   NaN         NaN         NaN
6   0.489553    0.012511    B   0.332927    0.010692    86.105553
7   0.677083    0.011934    B   0.489553    0.012511    -325.008666
8   0.810815    0.028882    B   0.677083    0.011934    7.890725
9   0.967808    0.365916    B   0.810815    0.028882    0.465808
```

and you can run `df.drop(['foo_prev','bar_prev'], axis =1, inplace = True)` if you don't want to see the workings after you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
foo_diff = demo.groupby('baz')['foo'].diff()
bar_diff = demo.groupby('baz')['bar'].diff()
demo['gradient'] = foo_diff/bar_diff
```

Result:

```
    foo         bar         baz gradient
0   0.023939    0.027107    A   NaN
1   0.180167    0.070630    A   3.589550
2   0.316840    0.014774    A   -2.446881
3   0.497396    0.059228    A   4.061637
4   0.632713    0.033585    A   -5.276957
5   0.332927    0.010692    B   NaN
6   0.489553    0.012511    B   86.105553
7   0.677083    0.011934    B   -325.008666
8   0.810815    0.028882    B   7.890725
9   0.967808    0.365916    B   0.465808
```